# Firebase Authentication automatically logs in into the account it was logged out from without inputting the email and password

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am am using firebase authentication and firestore to create users authentication on my website.

However after successfully creating my user authentication using  the firebase method `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, and `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, I can't seem to logOut current user.

My `onAuthStateChanged` wont let me especially on the component on which it is called. What I mean is that, if I call the `onAuthStateChanged` on the sign-in component, when I navigate to sign-in page, I am automatically signed into the account that I logged out from. If the `onAuthStateChanged`  method is called on the home component, when I navigate to home, I am automatically signed into the account that I logged out from.
Please what can i do to ensure that when i logged out of an account, i can only get back in by using email and password to sign-in?

Here is register and sign-in code

```
  const collectionUserRef = collection(db, "user");

  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // SignIn WithGoogle
  const SignInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      const popup = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
      const user = popup.user;
      const Query = query(collectionUserRef, where("uid", "===", 
user.uid));
      const docs = await getDocs(Query);
      if (docs.docs.legnth === 0)
        await (collectionUserRef,
        {
          uid: user?.uid,
          name: user?.displayName,
          email: user?.email,
          iamge: user?.photo,
          authProvider: popup?.providerId,
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };

 // SignIn WithEmailandPassword handler
  const signInHandleSubmit = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };

 // SignUp WithEmailandPassword handler
  const signUpHandleSubmit = async (
    firstname,
    lastname,
    username,
    email,
    password
  ) => {
    try {
      const userCredentials = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );
      const user = userCredentials.user;

      await addDoc(collectionUserRef, {
        uid: user.uid,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        username,
        providerId: "email/password",
        email: user.email,
      });

      await updateProfile(user, { displayName: username });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };
```

this is my onAuthStateChanged method in my home component

```
useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      if (currentUser) {
        setUser(currentUser);
        setLoading(true);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, [setUser]);
```

below is how i used it on my register and sign in page

```
//USER NAMES AND PASSWORD RULES
const NAME_REGX = /^[a-zA-Z-]{3,23}$/;
const USER_REGX = /^[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9-_]{3,23}$/;
const PWD_REGX =
  /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+{}\[\]:;<>,.?
```

~\/-]).{4,24}$/;

```
const EMAIL_REGX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;

const Rgistration = () => {
  const { signUpHandleSubmit } = useGlobalContext();

 
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
  const [firsNameFocus, setFirstNameFocus] = useState(false);
  const [validFirstName, setvalidFirstName] = useState(false);

  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("");
  const [lastNameFocus, setLastNameFocus] = useState(false);
  const [validLastName, setvalidLastName] = useState(false);

  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [validUser, setValidUser] = useState(false);
  const [userFocus, setUserFocus] = useState(false);

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [validEmail, setValidEmail] = useState(false);
  const [emailFocus, setEmailFocus] = useState(false);

  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState("");
  const [validPwd, setValidPwd] = useState(false);
  const [pwdFocus, setPwdFocus] = useState(false);

  const [matchPwd, setMatchPwd] = useState("");
  const [validMatch, setValidMatch] = useState(false);
  const [matchFocus, setMatchFocus] = useState(false);

  //On logiN
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");
  // const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    userRefFocus.current.focus();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkNameRules = NAME_REGX.test(firstName);
    setvalidFirstName(checkNameRules);
  }, [firstName]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkNameRules = NAME_REGX.test(lastName);
    setvalidLastName(checkNameRules);
  }, [lastName]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkUserRules = USER_REGX.test(user);
    console.log(checkUserRules);
    console.log(user);
    setValidUser(checkUserRules);
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkEmailRules = EMAIL_REGX.test(email);
    console.log(checkEmailRules);
    console.log(email);
    setValidEmail(checkEmailRules);
  }, [email]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkPWDRules = PWD_REGX.test(pwd);
    console.log(checkPWDRules);
    console.log(pwd);
    setValidPwd(checkPWDRules);
    const pwdMatch = pwd === matchPwd;
    setValidMatch(pwdMatch);
  }, [pwd, matchPwd]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setErrorMsg("");
  }, [user, pwd, matchPwd]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //if button enabled with JS hack
    const v1 = USER_REGX.test(user);
    const v2 = EMAIL_REGX.test(email);
    const v3 = PWD_REGX.test(pwd);
    const v4 = NAME_REGX.test(firstName);
    const v5 = NAME_REGX.test(lastName);
    const v6 = PWD_REGX.test(matchPwd);

    if (v1 && v2 && v3 && v4 && v5 && v6) {
      try {
        await signUpHandleSubmit(firstName, lastName, user, email, 
pwd);
        setLoading(true);
        navigate("/SignIn");
        console.log("Account succesfully created");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error Occured during registration:", error);
        if (error.response) {
          console.error("Firebase Error response:", 
error.response.data);
        }
      }
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
      alert("There is a missing field");
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="Register-card">
   //input details
    </section>
  );
};

//Sig-in component

const USER_REGX =
  /^(?:[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9-_]{3,23}|[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.
```

[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/;
const PWD_REGX =
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:;<>,.?
~\/-]).{4,24}$/;

```
const SignIn = () => {
  const userRefFocus = useRef();
  const errorRefAlert = useRef();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [usernameOrEmail, setUsernameOrEmail] = useState("");
  const [validUsernameOrEmail, setValidUsernameOrEmail] = 
useState(false);

  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState("");
  const [validPwd, setValidPwd] = useState(false);
  const [pwdFocus, setPwdFocus] = useState(false);

  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("");

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const { signInHandleSubmit, SignInWithGoogle, user, userData } =
    useGlobalContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkUserRules = USER_REGX.test(usernameOrEmail);
    console.log(checkUserRules);
    console.log(usernameOrEmail);
    setValidUsernameOrEmail(checkUserRules);
  }, [usernameOrEmail]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkPwdRules = PWD_REGX.test(pwd);
    console.log(checkPwdRules);
    console.log(pwd);
    setValidPwd(checkPwdRules);
  }, [pwd]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setErrorMsg("");
  }, [usernameOrEmail, pwd]);

  //Sign in handler
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const v1 = USER_REGX.test(usernameOrEmail);
    const v2 = PWD_REGX.test(pwd);
    if (v1 && v2) {
      try {
        await signInHandleSubmit(usernameOrEmail, pwd);
        setLoading(true);
        navigate("/");
      } catch (error) {
         navigate("/SignIn");
        console.error("Error Occured while signing in:", error);
        alert("Invalid Username/Email/Password");
      }
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
      navigate("/SignIn");
      alert("Invid Username/Email/Password");
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="Register-card">
 sign in details
    </section>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase by default preserves user that has been signed in, so if you refresh the page user would be signed in

To signOut you need to call specific function to let firebase remove user session

```
import { getAuth, signOut } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
signOut(auth).then(() => {
  // Sign-out successful.
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Comment: If you want to signin with another account on signInPage, signout before calling signInHandleSubmit

Comment: I did that i have a SignOut handle but still get logged in automatically

Comment: I do not see any signOut executions in your code, double check your components, if you have it, provide update to your question